# Get coordinates in a scaled and translated canvas

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I'm drawing an image to a scaled and translated HTML5 canvas. It's zoomed to a certain point on the image to be more specific, so only a smaller partition is visible. In this smaller part, I want to select a point, and calculate the point relative to the *original* image. Here is an illustration:

[image: Here is an illustration.]

There is [a similar answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717001/html5-canvas-get-coordinates-after-zoom-and-translate/21719256#21719256), which is explaining the canvas transformation nicely, but only shows how to get the point *relative to the scaled image*. What is the function, which gives the correct point described above?

**Update:**

There are three type of coordinates in this problem.

1. *Image point*: point on the image.
2. *Transformed point*: point on the transformed image, where the transformation can be scaling and translating.
3. *Viewport point*: a point from the visible area.

The transformation represented by the following matrix:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x' \\
        y' \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & c & e \\
        b & d & f \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

The only known data about the transformation (for me, at my current knowledge) is the transformation matrix, the original image size and the viewport size.

So, if I'm right, what needed here is the way, how can a viewport point converted to an image point.

Comment: So that we're talking the same language, what variables have you used for the translation and scale factor?

Comment: Those are varying, since the user can zoom in freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StackOverflow answer tells you how to change a viewport point to a transformed point. What you want to do is change a viewport point to an image point. To do this, you need to take the [inverse of the matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html). Basically, the inverse of a matrix does the exact opposite of what the original matrix did. For example, if the original matrix zooms in by a factor of $2$, then the inverse zooms out by a factor of $2$. This allows us to go from a viewport point to an image point given the transformation matrix.

However, the matrix of HTML5 canvas transformations can not be inversed because it is $2 \times 3$ and not $3 \times 3$ or some other square matrix. However, to fix this, we add the row $0 \ 0 \ 1$ to the bottom of the matrix. This works because the way `translate` and `scale` actually works in terms of regular matrices and vectors is that it uses a $3 \times 3$ matrix, except the last row is always $0 \ 0 \ 1$, and it uses a 3D point, except the $z$ coordinate is always $1$. Thus, if we add $0 \ 0 \ 1$ to the end of the matrix, we'll be able to take the inverse of it and find the image point given the viewport point. To take the inverse of a matrix in JavaScript, use [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/inv.html):

```
function turnArrayIntoMatrix(fakeMatrix) {
    /* fakeMatrix is our array of 6 elements that we need
       to turn into a multi-dimensional 3x3 array: */
    //realMatrix is the real matrix we will return:
    var realMatrix = [[], [], [0, 0, 1]];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //Add the (2*i)th element to the first row:
        realMatrix[0].push(fakeMatrix[2*i]);
        //Add the (2*i+1)th element to the second row:
        realMatrix[1].push(fakeMatrix[2*i+1]);
    }
    //Finally, return realMatrix:
    return realMatrix;
}
function turnMatrixIntoArray(realMatrix) {
    /* realMatrix is the 3x3 multi-dimensional array
       that we need to turn back into our six-element array: */
    //array is the array we're going to return:
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //Push the first and second element from each column into array:
        array.push(array[0][i]);
        array.push(array[1][i]);
    }
    //Finally, return array:
    return array;
}
//This shows us the inverse of our matrix:
console.log(turnMatrixIntoArray(math.inv(turnArrayIntoMatrix(matrix))));
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think this is not the solution. I updated the post with some clarifications. Anyway, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Morrel If you tell me how to get from a transformed point to a viewport point, I can tell you how to get from a viewport point to a transformed point and then we can combine that with how to get from a transformed point to the original point to go from a viewport point to the original.

Comment: To be honest, I have zero linear algebra knowledge, I don't understand how this matrix magic works. I'm using two canvas API's, the translate (shift the canvas horizontally and vertically with a given amount), and the scale (multiplying the coordinates with a value), then saving the transform matrix (sadly, there is no web API to get that with one function call). With these I create zoom (place the zoom point to the origo, scale, place back). The values are varying, because the user can move this simple camera to any point on the image, and zoom with any value. Is this helps?

Comment: It does, but this will take me a while to figure this out. I will probably come back to this question after a few days/a week and edit my answer. Then, I'll notify you here when I've done that.

Comment: @Morrel I'm sorry that it's taking me so long to respond to this question; I kind of forgot about it after a while. Again, I'm really sorry. Have you figured out the solution for yourself yet? I assume that was why you accepted my answer.

Comment: Absolutely no problem, your answer was almost what I needed. I edited it, so now is totally correct. Can you accept the edit, please? And thank you very much the help!

Comment: @Morrel Unfortunately, even though this is my post, only people with over 2,000 reputation can review edits, so I can't accept your edit. However, I did view it and I think I adjusted my code above correctly to answer your question. I also changed all of the wording at the top to make it the same way it was in your edit. I based it off your first attempt, not your second attempt, because I didn't notice your second attempt until after I had finished editing my answer.

Comment: @Morrel I just realized I had some typos in my code, so I edited my answer again.

Comment: Yeah, I found those two weeks ago, just forgot to edit back then. But this shows why I simplified the code. Those cycles hides the errors. Simplicity is very important is programming.